# Vertically align multiple lines beside a floated image

Tags: css, anchor, html, alignment

```
<li> 
    <a href="viewBook.php?bookId=<?=$bookId?>"> 
         <img style="float:left; clear:left; padding-left:10px; width:50px; height:75px;" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x75/000/fff" / >
         <span style="line-height:75px; padding-left:5px; color:grey;"><?=$count?>.</span>
         <span style=""><?=$title?></span>
     </a>
</li>
```

because i wanted to make a large clickable anchor area, so i have to throw everything inside an anchor. problem is because my title may be multiple lines. how could i actually vertically align to center of the image and preventing the next line of title from going below of the image.

demo link: jsfiddle.net/9wJRG/3

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code? You can get a dummy image [from here](http://dummyimage.com/).

Comment: Does this look like your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/9wJRG/ If not, change it so it does. Then link it here.

Comment: problem is with `line-height:75px;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9wJRG/3/ . i have updated it. because i wanted to make both spans vertically center to the image. any alternative to achieved so to prevent multiple lines going down to the image?

Comment: maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BzmVp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drop the two `span` elements and replace them with a single `span` element like this:

```
<li> 
    <a href="viewBook.php?bookId=<?=$bookId?>"> 
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x75/000/fff"/>
        <span id="text">
            <?=$count?>. <?=$title?>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and then use the following CSS for that `span`:

```
#text {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3T7ZT/2/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: +1 but this won't work in IE6 or IE7 (no support for `display:table-cell`). Just wanted to let the OP know.

Comment: millions thanks ^^. this is what i want thx! nvm i will just dump the IE problem aside first

Comment: @andyb: Fair enough :) Thank you !

Comment: @user723360: Glad to be of help !

Comment: This is not valid HTML IIRC. You can not have a div within an anchor

Comment: @MiG: You did recall correctly. I have edited my solution to reflect that, thank you for pointing it out !